# IP check does not work when I use OutputCache

Tags: c#, asp.net, outputcache

I use basic ip check for authentication like this:

masterpage.cs (I use just for Page.aspx, not Restricted.aspx):

```
string ip = Request.UserHostAddress;
    if (ip != "192.168.100.100" && ip != "192.168.101.101)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Restricted.aspx");
    }
```

It's working for me, because I don't need more complex authentication method.

But when I use `OutputCache`, it's not working. And all ips can see this page(Page.aspx) with cache.

Page.aspx:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="180" Location="Server" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

How can I use that with OutputCache?

Comment: I believe you are caching 'Restricted.aspx'. users will be able to see this page only after they pass 'if' condition right?what do you mean 'all ips can see this page'?

Comment: and its not going to work because you cache the page on server.... place on cache only a part of the page, the most easy way is to use a custom control with cache

Comment: I don't use cache for `Restricted.aspx`. "All ips can see this page" mean `Page.aspx`. I use check ip for `Page.aspx`. I use `masterpage.cs` for `Page.aspx` not `Restricted.aspx`.

Comment: Or how can I use "IP check" with other ways? Must be work with cache.

Comment: You have two requirements that cannot both be met. You want to run *code* to decide whether to provide access, but you also want to store the page in the cache - which means no code runs. Any reason for not putting the IP restrictions in IIS instead of your code?

Comment: I need to use custom IP restrictions for every page. How can I do this with IIS?